# Vue - Select all checkbox

Tags: vue.js

I'm relatively new to Vue so bare with me on this.

I have a v-for which produces a list of checkboxes, these all individually function correctly if I were to click on them separately, what I am after, like the title says is a select all checkbox to sit ontop which selects all in the list, but I'm running into a few issues which I don't understand, see relevant code below:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#lister-app",
    mixins: [pagination, baseDownloadParent],
    components: { selectField, articleItem, documentItem },
    data: {
      facets: {},
      isCheckAll: false,
    },
    computed: {
      getFacets() {
        return this.facets;
      },
      getFacetsLength() {
        return this.facets.length;
      },
    },
    methods: {
      toggleSelect(item, facet) {
        if (!this.params[facet.name]) Vue.set(this.params, facet.name, []);
        const existElem = this.params[facet.name].findIndex((el) => {
          return el === item.identifier;
        });

        if (existElem !== -1) this.params[facet.name].splice(existElem, 1);
        else this.params[facet.name].push(item.identifier);
      },
      checkAll(){
        console.log('FunctionWhichChecksAll');
      },
    },
});
```

```html
 <label class="option-checkbox" for="Select all">
    <input id="Select all" class="option-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" @click='checkAll()' v-model='isCheckAll'>
    <span class="option-checkbox__text">Select all</span>
    <span class="option-checkbox__icon"></span>
</label>
<option-field inline-template v-for="(item, i) in facet.items" :for="item.name" :key="i + item.name">
    <label class="option-checkbox">
        <input :id="item.name" class="option-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" v-model="checked"  @change="toggleSelect(item, facet)">
        <span class="option-checkbox__text">{{item.name}} </span>
        <span class="option-checkbox__icon"></span>
    </label>
</option-field>
```

What I am picturing is as  piece of script which is inside the checkAll() function?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo, based on your code (simplified):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-prghrq?file=src%2FApp.vue

Checkboxes in Vue can sometimes be a mess, when you combine `v-model` with `@click` handlers and especially if you have a check-all field. That's why I usually don't use `v-models` for it. Using only the `:checked` value as a one-way binding makes it easier to read and to maintain. With the `click` handler you can then update the state of each entry.